# Batch Opening Hyperlinks Opens Each Link Twice

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this macro on a selected column of hyperlinks, two tabs open for each link.

```
Sub BatchOpenHyperLinks_SelectedRanges()
    Dim objSelectedRange As Excel.Range
    Dim objHyperlink As Excel.Hyperlink

    'Get selected ranges
    Set objSelectedRange = Excel.Application.Selection
    For Each objHyperlink In objSelectedRange.Hyperlinks
        objHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running this code from outside of Excel? You don't need to declare your objects like that from within the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check your selection. I tested this and only one tab opened:

```
Sub BatchOpenHyperLinks_SelectedRanges()
    Dim thisHyperlink As Hyperlink
    For Each thisHyperlink In Selection.Hyperlinks
        thisHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```